# Errors: unhashable type 'dict' when use Cloud Dataflow Writing to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I need to write data to Bigquery from pub/sub through apache-beam.The code looks like the following:

```py
import argparse
import base64
import logging
import json
from datetime import datetime
from ast import literal_eval
from google.cloud import bigquery

import apache_beam as beam


class DataIngestion(beam.DoFn):

    @classmethod
    def parse_method(cls, string_input):
        """
        :param string_input:
        :return:
        """
        try:
            pubsub_message = literal_eval(string_input.data.decode('utf8'))
            process_data = pubsub_message['data']
            print('- ' * 20)
            regex = '\n'
            for i in process_data.split(regex)[:-1]:
                d = eval(i)
                d['dt'] = "{}".format(datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
                return json.loads(d)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(e)
            
def run(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--input_subscription', required=False,
                        help='Input PubSub subscription of the form "projects/<project>/subscriptions/<subscription_name>".',
                        default='projects/subscriptions/client_sub')
    parser.add_argument('--output', dest='output', required=False,
                        help='Output BQ table to write results to.',
                        default='project:fm.client_event')

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    with beam.Pipeline(argv=pipeline_args) as p:
        lines = p | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.input_subscription, with_attributes=True)
        table_info = 'project:fm.client_event'
        table_schema = 'app_version:STRING, build:INTEGER, channel:STRING, client_ip:STRING, client_ip:STRING...'
        transformed = (
            lines
            | 'String to BigQuery Row' >> beam.Map(lambda s: DataIngestion.parse_method(s))
            | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                                     table_info,
                                     schema=table_schema,
                                     create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                     write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
        )

    transformed.run().wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

this job is try to split and parse data to single row and write to bigquery by using
`beam.io.WriteToBigQuery`,This is resulting in the following stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bigquery_io_write.py", line 68, in <module>
    run()
  File "./bigquery_io_write.py", line 57, in run
    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

It's strange that I didn't pass any dict to the `WriteToBigQuery`,and I have tried to modify the schema of pub/sub's data or even delete the `create_disposition` and `write_disposition`.
It looks like some parameter's transfer is going wrong somewhere,I have verified that it has nothing to do with the data format of `parse_method` function，the job faied before excuting that step.

Comment: please ignore the syntax error in parse_method's loop...

Answer (score 0):

`parse_method` returns the result of the call `json.loads(d)`. According to [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html#module-json), `json.loads` returns a dictionary.

Also, the return statement is inside the for loop, so you parse only the first line in each message. Did you want to use a generator instead?

Comment: Apologize for my mistake,this code block's formatting error due to I deleted sensitive data.Please ignore the loop code,it seems to have no effect on the error.

Comment: Then it looks like the error comes from the data being fed to the BigQuery sync. Have you tried writing some static content? The records you write can be dictionaries, but the data in each field should follow the proper schema. Without an update code snippet and a data example, I won't be able to help much more than this advice.